# Why am i getting "Route [/login] not defined error" in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, post, routes

I'm trying to upload a file (.csv) with the help of HTML form (blade file) and a function inside my **Maincontroller.php**. But as soon as i press the submit button after uploading a file, it displays the Errors "InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php" followed by "Route [/login] not defined."

My **uploadform.blade.php** file is :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="datafile" />
            <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My **uploadFile** function (inside *MainController.php* file) signature is :

```
public function uploadFile() {

    /* ------------------- */

    /* I WANT TO REACH HERE */

    /* ------------------- */
}
```

And, in the routes file (i.e. inside **web.php** file) is :

```
Route::post('/upload-file', 'MainController@uploadFile');
```

---

On a side note, upon replacing the **post** keyword with the **get** keyword (in the blade and route files), the **uploadFile** function is getting triggered, but it is of no use for me, as file upload (and accessing the csv file data) won't work with GET method.

Comment: Have you cleared the route cache?

Comment: @DsRaj Yes, its not affecting anything.

Comment: update the action="{{ action('MainController@uploadFile') }}" as I think the URL might be problem

Comment: @DsRaj Just fixed it using the {{csrf_token}} in uploadform.blade.php file. Think its not a very palpable solution, but got it fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Route [/login] not defined.

So somewhere (most probably in a blade file) you got that wrong like this `route('/login')` and should be `route('login')`.

Do a global search through whole project for `/login` and fix it. :)

Also check if this route exists by typing `php artisan route:list` in console/terminal.

```
| Domain | Method    | URI   | Name  | Action                                                  | Middleware |
|--------|-----------|-------|-------|---------------------------------------------------------|------------|
|        | GET|HEAD  | login | login | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | login | login | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login         | web,guest  |
```

Comment: Just fixed it using the {{csrf_token}} in **uploadform.blade.php** file. Think its not a very palpable solution, but got it fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that for uploading the file your system require user to be logged in. And the framework redirects it to login route.
Probably you don't have Auth routes and that is why you get 404.
`php artisan make:auth` will add default routes and views
Then add to routes.php `Auth::routes();` (if doesn't exists)
Check Laravel documentation: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: Just fixed it using the {{csrf_token}} in **uploadform.blade.php** file. Think its not a very palpable solution, but got it fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just got it fixed using the **{{csrf_token}}** in **uploadform.blade.php** file. Think its not a very palpable solution, but got it fixed.
But, any more **explanation** regarding this is very much welcome.
Thanks